# How to restore postgres database into another database name

Tags: postgresql

I use the postgres today
and got a problem
I dump the database that way

```
 pg_dump zeus_development -U test > zeus_development.dump.out
```

what if I wnat to restore to another database zeus_production

How could I do?

Comment: Side note - it might be better to use one of the binary dump format instead of plain text. It will speed up the dump/restore process, reduces the size of the dump file and gives some additional ways to controll the restoration process. Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simple, first create your database using `template0` as your [template database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

```
createdb -U test -T template0 zeus_production
```

Then, restore your dump on this database:

```
psql -U test zeus_production -f /path/to/zeus_development.dump.out
```

When restoring, always use `template0` explicit, as it is always an empty and unmodifiable database. If you don't use an explicit template, PostgreSQL will assume `template1`, and if it has some objects, like a table or function that your dumped database already has, you will get some errors while restoring.

Nonetheless, even if you were restoring on a database with the same name (`zeus_development`) you should create (or recreate) it the same way. Unless you used `-C` option while dumping (or `-C` of `pg_restore` if using a binary dump), which I don't recommend, because will give you less flexibility (like restoring on a different database name).

Answer (score 28):

The PostgresSQL documentation has influenced me to use the custom format.  I've been using it for years and it seems to have various advantages but your mileage may vary.  That said, here is what worked for me:

```sh
pg_restore --no-owner --dbname postgres --create ~/Desktop/pg_dump 
psql --dbname postgres -c 'ALTER DATABASE foodog_production RENAME TO foodog_development'
```

There was no `foodog_development` nor `foodog_production` databases existing before the sequence.

This restores the database from the dump (`~/Desktop/pg_dump`) which will create it with the name it was dumped as. The rename names the DB to whatever you want.

The `--no-owner` may not be needed if your user name is the same on both machines.  In my case, the dump was done as `user1` and the restore done as `user2`. The new objects need to be owned by `user2` and `--no-owner` achieves this.

Comment: I use the custom format universally because text format often fails on restore. This answer is the most useful to me.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't it easier to simply do the following?

```
createdb -U test -T zeus_development zeus_production
```

Comment: Actually, the above does work.  The original question did not mention he was moving to a new machine.  It was just assumed.  The -T option is quite power.

Comment: That's great. It safes me a lot of time. Simple and easy.

Comment: Wouldn't this take double disk space?

Comment: How does this work if restoring onto a new machine, that is, dumping from MachineA, but restoring on MachineB?

Answer (score 6):

This has an [answer on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/246215/91147), which I reproduce here:

Let's define a few variables to make the rest easier to copy/paste

```sh
old_db=my_old_database
new_db=new_database_name
db_dump_file=backups/my_old_database.dump
user=postgres
```

The following assumes that your backup was created with the "custom" format like this:

```
pg_dump -U $user -F custom $old_db > "$db_dump_file"
```

To restore `$db_dump_file` to a new database name `$new_db` :

```
dropdb   -U $user --if-exists  $new_db
createdb -U $user -T template0 $new_db

pg_restore -U $user -d $new_db "$db_dump_file"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your dump does not include the name, the restore will use the DB defined in `DESTINATION`. Both `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION` are [Connection URLs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).

Dump without `--create`

```
pg_dump \
  --clean --if-exists \
  --file ${dump_path} \
  --format=directory \
  --jobs 5 \
  --no-acl \
  --no-owner \
  ${SOURCE}
```

Restore without `--create`

```
pg_restore \
  --clean --if-exists \
  --dbname=${DESTINATION} \
  --format=directory \
  --jobs=5 \
  --no-acl \
  --no-owner \
  $dump_path
```

Comment: This worked seamlessly, no issues with foreign keys or anything, unlike when I used `psql` and a text dump. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mmel for the answer. But this I tweaked that works mine:

Dump:

```
pg_dump \
  --file {filename}.tar \
  --format=tar \
  --no-acl \
  --no-owner \
  --no-privileges \
  -U {username} \
  -h {host} \
  -p {port} \
  {db-name}
```

Restore:

```
pg_restore \
  --format=tar \
  --no-acl \
  --no-owner \
  --no-privileges \
  -U {username} \
  -h {host} \
  -p {port} \
  {db-name}
  {same-filename-as-dump}.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **hacky** way of doing it, that *only* works if you can afford the space and time to use regular `.sql` format, and if you can safely `sed` out your database name and user.

```
$ pg_dump -U my_production_user -h localhost my_production > my_prod_dump.sql
$ sed -i 's/my_production_user/my_staging_user/g' my_prod_dump.sql
$ sed -i 's/my_production/my_staging/g' my_prod_dump.sql
$ mv my_prod_dump.sql my_staging_dump.sql

$ sudo su postgres -c psql
psql> drop database my_staging;
psql> create database my_staging owner my_staging_user;
psql> \c my_staging;
psql> \i my_staging_dump.sql
```